# Kotlin partition command not working as expected

Tags: kotlin

i am using '1.2.60' version of the kotlin plugin. and from the docs it says that partition should split an collection based on some predicate.  But when i try it its not splitting into pairs both true and false results. let me show you whats happening and what i have tried:

```
val(found,notFound) = "abcd".partition { "abcdef".contains(it)}
```

here i am expecting that i will get back a Kotlin Pair. the first would be "abcd" and i want the second to be "ef"
What i am trying to do is if any char is not in one string then it should be seperated.  so since "ef" is not in "abcd" it should be parititioned .

To be clear i am expecting that `found = "abcd" , notFound = "ef"`

but instead when i run this code i get the following:  `found="abcd" ,notFound=""`

why is notFound empty, what am i doing wrong ? can you guys try it and let me know ?

if we check [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/partition.html) it says this partition command should be split by predicate:

> Splits the original string into pair of strings, where first string contains characters for which predicate yielded true, while second string contains characters for which predicate yielded false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partition is applied to `"abcd"`. So this string is partitioned in a pair.  
`"abcdef".contains(it)` is a predicate that returns always true.  
So the result is for `found` the whole partitioned string and for `notFound` nothing.  
For the solution that propose Todd and leonardkraemer I'm not sure that this is what you need.  
For example:

```
val(found, notFound) = "abcdefa".partition { "abcd".contains(it) }
```

returns:

```
found = abcda
notFound = ef
```

Is this what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

You swapped the arguments. Try

```
val(found,notFound) = "abcdef".partition { "abcd".contains(it)}
```

and you will get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have your strings backwards.

I was able to get the results you want with this:

```
val (found, notFound) = "abcdef".partition { "abcd".contains(it) }
```